# LWC 1001 and LWC 1002 Error

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, superbadges

getting these 2 errors while deploying boatSearchResult component of lwc superbadge.

> LWC1002: Error in module resolution: Error when using sourcemap for
> reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error. (7:9)
> LWC1001: Unexpected compilation error: Unexpected token (Note that you
> need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript) (7:9)

any help where am doing wrong.

```
import { LightningElement, wire,track, api } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import getBoats from '@salesforce/apex/BoatDataService.getBoats';
import updateBoatList from '@salesforce/apex/BoatDataService.updateBoatList';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import BoatMC from '@salesforce/messageChannel/BoatMessageChannel__c';


const SUCCESS_TITLE = 'Success';
const MESSAGE_SHIP_IT = 'Ship it!';
const SUCCESS_VARIANT = 'success';
const ERROR_TITLE = 'Error';
const ERROR_VARIANT = 'error';
const columns = [
  {label:'Name', fieldName:'Name', type:'text', editable:'true'},
  {label:'Length', fieldName :'Length__c', type:'number', editable:'true'},
  {label:'Price', fieldName:'Price__c', type:'currecny', editable:'true'},
  {label:'Description', fieldName:'Description__c', type:'text', editable:'true'}
];

export default class BoatSearchResults extends LightningElement {
  
  selectedBoatId = '';
  boatTypeId = '';
  @track boats;
  isLoading = false;

  boatColumns = columns;
  @track boatDraftValues = [];
  
  // wired message context
  @wire(MessageContext)
  messageContext;

  // wired getBoats method
  @wire(getBoats, {boatTypeId : '$boatTypeId'})
  wiredBoats(result){
    if(result.data){
        this.boats = result;
    }
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.notifyLoading(this.isLoading);
   }
  
  // public function that updates the existing boatTypeId property
  // uses notifyLoading
  @api 
  searchBoats(boatTypeId){
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.notifyLoading(this.isLoading);
    this.boatTypeId = boatTypeId;
  }
  
  // this public function must refresh the boats asynchronously
  // uses notifyLoading
  async refresh(){ 
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.notifyLoading(this.isLoading);

    await refreshApex(this.boats);

    this.isLoading = false;
    this.notifyLoading(this.isLoading);
  }
  
  // this function must update selectedBoatId and call sendMessageService
  updateSelectedTile(event){
    this.selectedBoatId = event.boatId;
    this.sendMessageService(this.selectedBoatId);
  }
  
  // Publishes the selected boat Id on the BoatMC.
  sendMessageService(boatId){ 
    // explicitly pass boatId to the parameter recordId
    const payload = {recordId : boatId};
    publish(this.messageContext, BoatMC, payload);
  }
  
  // The handleSave method must save the changes in the Boat Editor
  // passing the updated fields from draftValues to the 
  // Apex method updateBoatList(Object data).
  // Show a toast message with the title
  // clear lightning-datatable draft values
  handleSave(event){
    // notify loading
    this.boatDraftValues = event.detail.draftValues;
    const updatedFields = event.detail.draftValues;
    // Update the records via Apex
    updateBoatList({data: updatedFields})
    .then(() => {
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({title : SUCCESS_TITLE, message : MESSAGE_SHIP_IT, variant : SUCCESS_VARIANT})
      );
      this.boatDraftValues = [];
      return this.refresh();
    })
    .catch(error => {
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new ShowToastEvent({title : ERROR_TITLE, message : error.body.message, variant : ERROR_VARIANT})
      );  
    })
    .finally(() => {
      this.boatDraftValues = [];
    });
  }
  
  // Check the current value of isLoading before dispatching the doneloading or loading custom event
  notifyLoading(isLoading){ 
    if(isLoading){
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('loading'));
    }else{
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('doneloading'));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This complains about line number 7 where you import `@salesforce/messageChannel/BoatMessageChannel__c`, I think the messaging channel (BoatMessageChannel__c) is not deployed correctly. Please verify that.

Comment: @Raul, MessageChannel got deployed successfully...but when i deploy package.xml file, getting same error again.

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and tried to deploy to a dev org. It got deployed. I deployed the message channel and apex class first and then the lwc folder.